# How can I figure out which key is pressed in older Android sdk (<12)

Tags: android, keyevent

I've got a problem, I wrote a function that override the onKeyDown, so to know the button pressed i wrote this:

```
KeyEvent.keyCodeToString(keyCode).replace("KEYCODE_", "");
```

All worked but when i tried to run the app in a older device with an sdk < 12 (3.1) it says that there are no such method.

So how can i do to know the pressed button value?

Comment: what keycode are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the method was added later though as a help you can use `getDisplayLabel` for basic keys but this will only return you one char representing the label of the button pressed.
Now, as the KeyEvents are Ints and not an enum, it's not really easy to get the name of the code as it's only the name of the variable. You could try using reflection to get the keycode's variable name but it seems a heavy mechanism if you start logging every button the user presses...